# How to use TableRegistry in CakePHP component?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am new in cakephp, and trying to create a component using **cakephp version 4.0.7** .

In component I need to save data in a table. I have followed this [documentation on inserting data](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#inserting-data)

In component I have tried below code for registry My table

```
use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;

class MyComponent extends Component{

    public function foo()
    {
         $ProductsTable = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Products');
    }

}
```

In output I am getting below exception

```
Call to undefined method App\Controller\Component\MyComponent::getTableLocator()
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `use Vendor\SomeTrait;` declaration should be inside class, not outside.  Thats how traits work. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CakePHP 4.0.x**

```
$productsTable = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Products');
```

**from CakePHP 4.1**

> Cake\ORM\TableRegistry has been deprecated. Use
> Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait::getTableLocator() or
> Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator::get('Table')

read https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-1-migration-guide.html#orm

**and try to use FactoryLocator:**

```
use Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator;

$productsTable = FactoryLocator::get('Table')->get('Products');

//$productsTable->find()...
```

**or inject trait inside component class**

```
class MyComponent extends Component{

    use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;

    public function foo()
    {
         $ProductsTable = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Products');
    }

}
```

Comment: For 1st one getting error 
Call to a member function get() on array

Comment: CakePHP version 4.0.x or 4.1.x?

Comment: cakephp version : 4.0.7

Comment: then use TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Products');

Answer (score 1):

Salines answere is still valid in **Cakephp 4.3.x** 
I tested it and it worked in my component!

```
class MyComponent extends Component{

    use Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator;

    public function foo()
    {  
        $ProductsTable = FactoryLocator::get('Table')->get('ProductsTable ');
    }

}
```